# Querying HTML attributes in Dart

Tags: firefox, dart

I have HTML in this format:

```html
<form name="fruit_name">
  <input id="fruit-name" type="hidden" name="Banana">
</form>
```

I have Dart querying the fruit name like this:

```dart
var fruitName = query('#fruit-name').attributes.values.last;
```

This works great in Chrome and Safari. But In Firefox, the attributes come back in a different order, so `name` is no longer last. What's the best way to grab the attribute I'm after without relying on the browser so much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`attributes` is a Map](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/Element.html#attributes), so this should work:

```dart
var fruitName = query('#fruit-name').attributes['name'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```dart
var fruitName = query('input#fruit-name').name;
```

The result of the `query` is in fact a [InputElement](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/InputElement.html) and you have more member that in a simple [Element](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/Element.html).

By prepending `#fruit-name` with `input` you will tell to the analyzer that the result of `query` is an `InputElement`. Without that you would get a warning ( *There is no such getter 'name' in 'Element'* ).

---

Finally, from a performance point of view, the best way to do this is with [document.getElementById(id)](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/Document.html#getElementById) because [`getElementById` is really faster than `querySelector`](http://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector) ) :

```dart
InputElement fruitNameElement = document.getElementById('fruit-name');
var fruitName = fruitNameElement.name;
```

Here, the first line allows to type `fruitNameElement` to prevent warning when calling `fruitNameElement.name`.